# possible memory leak using pointers with malloc() and free(), and confusion with pointer notation

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, singly-linked-list

So I'm relatively new to C, and I was trying to write code for a singly linked list.

This is what I wrote for deleting a node from the beginning of the list.

```
int delete(struct node **head)
{
    int x = -1;
    if(*head != NULL) {
        struct node *old = *head;
        (*head) = (*head)->next;
        x = old->data;
        free(old);
    }
    return x;
}
```

and I'm confused at the `free()` function. Am I freeing the space allocated to the pointer `old`, or am I freeing it to the address at which `old` points? Maybe the correct way of doing it would be `free(*old)`? Will this code cause a memory leak?

Also, if this frees the memory allocated to old, what would be the effect of `free(&old)`, in that case?

Comment: Did you try `free(*old);` or even `free(&old);`? Did it work? :-)

Comment: OT: In terms of robustness change `if(*head != NULL)` to be `if(head != NULL && *head != NULL)`.

Comment: *facepalms* I should have just tried those things in my code before asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you show the memory management seems OK and does not seem to leak memory.

> Am I freeing the space allocated to the pointer old

Yes, the code deallocates, frees to memory `old` points to, which is commonly referred to as *the memory being allocated to a pointer*.

---

`free(*old)` wouldn't work, as it wouldn't compile, because you tried to pass a `struct` into where a pointer is expected.

`free(&old)` wouldn't work, as it would provoke undefined behaviour, because the code tried to free memory being allocated on the stack, that is the memory for the pointer variable `old` itself.